# Optimal way to set state of another component from

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, state

there's a few posts explaining how to update state from another component but I'm still unable to parse the solution for my particular problem. I want the submit button in my `SideBar.js` component to trigger `nextProblem()` in my `tableA.js` component when it is clicked. This will cause the state of `tableA.js` to change as `problemNum` goes from `1` to `2`, generating a different form. I can't import `SideBar.js` component into my `tableA.js` due to my design layout though! `SideBar.js` also contains images. Any ideas?

I'm using a CSS grid for the layout of my page:

```
    grid-template-areas:
        "navbar navbar navbar navbar"
        "sidebar tableA ... ..."
        "sidebar tableA ... ..."
        "sidebar tableA ... ..."
```

I'm using App.js to route to the pages:

```
function App() {
  return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Routes>
              <Route path={"/"} exact element={<MainPage/>}/>
              <Route path={"/gamePage"} exact element={<GamePage/>}/>
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I created a `SideBar.js` component that contains a logo at the top and a `submit` button at the bottom:

```
class SideBar extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {

    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className={"sidebar"}>
                <div className={"logo_group"}>
                    <img className={"some_logo"} src={logo}/>
                </div>
                <div className={"nav_group"}>
                    <button className={"home"}/>
                    <button className={"about"}/>
                </div>
                <img className={"an_image"} src={someImage}/>
                <div className={"button_group"}>
                    <button className={"submit_button"} onClick={() => nextProblem()}>Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
         )
    }
}
export default SideBar
```

and a `tableA.js` component with a function `nextProblem()` that changes the state of the component:

```
class tableA extends Component {
    state = {
        problemNum: 1,
        problemStatus: 'unsolved',
        userAnswer: []
    };

    nextProblem = () => {
        this.setState(state => ({
            problemNum: state.problemNum + 1,
        }))
    }

    componentDidMount() {}

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form>
                     ...depends on the state of the problem number
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }

export default tableA
```

I then consolidate everything in `GamePage.js`:

```
const GamePage= () => {
    return (
        <div className={"gamepage-container"}>
            <div className={"navbar"}>
                <NavBar></NavBar>
            </div>
            <div className={"sidebar"}>
                <SideBar></SideBar>
            </div>
            <div className={"tableA"}>
                <TableA></TableA>
            </div>
            ...
        </div>
      )
}

export default GamePage
```

Comment: You might look at moving your state as well as `nextProblem` function to the parent `GamePage` component. Then, you can pass `nextProblem` as a prop to the `Sidebar` component and pass the state as props to the `Table` component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'd propably go the approach of letting the gamepage handle the state and such and send down the problem and the update function down the components as props. Depending on how big this thing will grow you could also use a centralized store.

```
const GamePage= () => {
    const [problem, setPropblem] = useState(0)

    return (
        <div className={"gamepage-container"}>
            <div className={"navbar"}>
                <NavBar></NavBar>
            </div>
            <div className={"sidebar"}>
                <SideBar 
                    onSetNext={() => setProblem(problem + 1)}
                ></SideBar>
            </div>
            <div className={"tableA"}>
                <TableA
                    problem={problem}
                ></TableA>
            </div>
            ...
        </div>
      )
}

export default GamePage
```

and in your sidebar the button becomes

```
<button className={"submit_button"} onClick={() => this.props.onSetNext()}>Submit</button>
```

similarly you access the props.propblem instead of state in your table.

Comment: It seems like TableA.js is rendering late. For example, all states are initialized at 1. At this point, TableA.js is showing form 1 correctly. I then hit submit, the counter increases to 2 and all components recognize this, yet TableA is still displaying form 1. I then hit Submit again, increasing the counter to 3, but now TableA is showing form 2. My intention is for form 1 to display when the counter is at 1 (submit wouldn't be pushed yet), and then form 2 to show when I hit the submit button (bringing the counter to 2), etc etc

Comment: you have a minimal implementation of your case? like on codesandbox?

Comment: thanks for your help mate - I solved this after a long night of tinkering - I added problem num as the dep in useEffect